# Position svg element higher on top of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this has been answered in other places because I've looked, but nothing I can find seems to do the trick, sorry for posting a question that's been asked before.

I just need to append a transparent svg element exactly over my canvas element, but whenever I append, the svg goes under the canvas, no matter what I try with positioning and z-index.

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry for my newb question, I'm new to coding. Here's the code I think is appropriate:

here's the css:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and the javascript for canvas:

```
var width = screen.width;
var height= screen.height;
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

and finally my javascript for creating and appending the element:

```
function getCanvas(canvas) {
    var top = canvas.css('top');
    var left = canvas.css('left');
    var canvaswidth = canvas.width();
    var canvasheight = canvas.height();
    var svg = $('<svg>Hey</svg>').attr({
        'xmlns': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        'width': canvaswidth,
        'height': canvasheight,
        'top': top,
        'left': left,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'opacity': 1,
        'id': 'svg'
    });
    svg.css({backgroundColor: 'black', 'z-index': 10});
    svg.insertAfter(canvas);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Uh.... is the function actually being called? Toss a `console.log("hi");` at the top of that function, and call up your js debugger. Might also wanna log the value of `canvas` because that being null would also cause this to not work.

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't need to have a `z-index` at all, since you svg is after your canvas element.

The problem comes from that the property `position` is not set the right way.
It is set as an attribute instead of as a style property.

```js
canvas = $('#canvas');
var svg = $('<svg><text x="50" y="50">Hey</text></svg>').attr({
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  id: 'svg'
}).css({
  position: 'absolute',
  top: canvas.css('top'),
  left: canvas.css('left'),
  width: canvas.width(),
  height: canvas.height(),
  opacity: 1,
});
svg.insertAfter(canvas);
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I should have specified, I'm calling the function manually in dev tools while I try to get it to work. and thanks for answering! that looks like it will work and I'll try when I clock out

Comment: Thought something looked weird about how those were being set, but I'm not overly well versed enough in jQ to call it out. Thanks haha